# Regex , How to obtain XXXX, given XXXX-yyyyy+12313123@you.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Given a email like: XXXX-yyyyy+12313123@you.com

I want regex to capture whatever XXXX is, which can be of variable length.

In ruby i'm trying:

```
model_type = to[/^(.*?)\-/,1]
```

But according to Rubular, that is capturing the trailing -, meaning XXXX- which I don't want. How do I exclude that dash?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for capture two types of patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866817/regex-for-capture-two-types-of-patterns)

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions. Modify your original question by re-editing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked rubular and it isn't capturing the trailing -

http://rubular.com/r/UJi4vSMx9H

Comment: Oh I see it highlights the dash but doesn't show the dash in the mash. Strange. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yes, you should be looking at matched captures for the captured array, and matched results for the regex matches.

Answer (score 1):

XXXX can't contain dash symbol, yes?

```
model_type = to[/^([^-]*)-/, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

All these regexes...

```
"XXXX-yyyyy+12313123@you.com".split('-').first
```